# Primary replica in primary DC freezes when delocalised DR replica DC crashes

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

The Always On hasn't got the flexibility of mirroring. The DR replica's data center crashed and the primary replica also froze as a result (see following error when trying to access the primary).

Is there a way around this? Some buffering that could allow the primary to continue working while the secondary replica is being fixed. There is a bit of all-or-nothing in this set up.

[image: Error message when trying connect to the primary replica when the secondary replica is down]

Comment: is the secondary replica configured as synchronous replica ? If so, change first to async and then do the maintenance on secondary.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue with your cluster configuration, not with Always On. Specifically, this occurs when you have two replicas but no witness in the underlying Failover Cluster.

A 2-replica Always On solution will keep the primary replica online when the secondary replica fails provided the underlying cluster is still up. If you don't have a quorum witness configured then when your DR replica went offline the cluster shut down to avoid split-brain because it could not achieve quorum. This is expected and essential behaviour for protecting the data integrity.

Check out this article for a good understanding of [cluster quorum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/understand-quorum) and take a look at this article on configuring a [quorum witness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/manage-cluster-quorum).